# jQuery tooltip on desktop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm looking for a way to display a tooltip (preferably jQuery's) on the lower right corner of the screen, even if the page itself is minimized.

Is there anyway to achieve this?

Thanks ahead

Answer (score 2):

This is only possible with the new API that's coming with HTML5. You can try it out [over here](http://www.onepixelahead.com/demos/html5Notifications/html5_notification_test.html).

*I'm not sure*, but at this moment the API is only available in Webkit based browsers like Google Chrome.